# JavaScript doesn't play too short audio files

Tags: javascript, r, audio

I'm new to JavaScript, and I'm trying to code a simple program where audio file is played onclick. The problem is that it seems like if the sound file is too small, it doesn't work (I see that it uploaded to my browser, but no sound).

Here is a [website](https://agricolamz.github.io/phonfieldwork/s1/stimuli_viewer.html), where you could click on ear emoji and there will be sound when the "tap" row is clicked, but not others.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function sound_play(x) {
   var audio = new Audio();
   audio.src = x;
   audio.play();
 }
```

The website is generated with R packages `rmarkdown` and `DT`, but this script I added on my own.

I'm checking on Firefox 71.0.

Comment: It works on latest chrome opera and safari

Comment: It is working totally fine on my browser i.e. Google Chrome (Version 79.0.3945.88).

Comment: Oh, it looks like it is a problem of my Firefox then, thanks you all!